GTM Server side tagging preview not logging requests
I am implementing Server Side tagging in GTM. I have created a server GTM container and have gone through all the steps of configuration. Now whenever i try to preview the web and server container i can see that the requests are going to my server container but tag manager debug is not showing any requests.
But if i copy the same URL and do a get request the request does logs onto the tag manager debug mode.

[Jun 2024] In the new version of Google Tag Manager only test events are logged in preview mode.
To send test events click on the 3 dots at the right top corner and select "Send request manually".
As explained in the modal:

Preview mode for your server container works the same way as it does for a web container. To send preview requests from your browser, just use your website as you normally would.
To manually send a preview request, or to send a preview request from a server application, add the X-Gtm-Server-Preview header to your HTTP request with the following value:

So you are not able to see production events in preview mode
Hope that helps
